# ECONNRESET Error When Running NPM Install Behind MITMproxy 9.0.1

Tags: python, ssl, npm, proxy, mitmproxy

So I am trying to run `npm install` behind a proxy. Specifically MITMproxy 9.0.1, hosted locally on the same machine as the build machine. I am running the following:

```bash
# Clear cache and artifacts
rm -rf package-lock.json ~/.npm node_modules
# Run Proxy
mitmdump --set stream_large_bodies=1m --ssl-insecure --listen-port 8989 &> stdout.txt &
# build command
npm install --registry=[registry] --force --legacy-peer-deps
```

Which results in the error:

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch [registry]/@angular-devkit%2fbuild-angular: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-16T16_07_07_514Z-debug-0.log
```

My `.npmrc` looks like this(running within a docker container for testing purposes, that's why it's using root):

```rc
cafile=/root/.mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem
https-proxy=https://127.0.0.1:8989
proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8989
```

And the `package.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "mitmdump-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0"
  }
}
```

## Environment

### OS

This was tested on Centos8, and Debian Bullseye. This behavior is seen both in containers and traditional VMs.

### Configuration

I discovered that NPM + MITMproxy could cause MITMproxy to barf, as it had too many open file descriptors(in the form of sockets). I got around this by increasing the max file descriptors using `ulimit -n 4096`. This seemed to avoid this problem.

## Solutions(hacks)

I have identified three actions which fix this. None are acceptable for me to actually do, for one reason or another. And secondly they do not seem to fix the core problem.

1. Downgrading MITMProxy
2. Invoking `npm install` with sudo
3. Accessing the registry using http instead of https

### Downgrading MITMProxy

This Python3/MITMproxy combo works as expected, no `ECONNRESET` error:

```
$ mitmdump --version
Mitmproxy: 5.3.0
Python:    3.6.8
```

But this Python3/MITMproxy combo fails as described above:

```
mitmdump --version
Mitmproxy: 9.0.1
Python:    3.10.4+
```

### Sudo

If you run the `npm install` command with sudo, with the version of Python/mitmdump that typically breaks it, it works properly. I mentioned above that I was testing using a docker container, but in this case, this is only a fix when running outside of root. I've tested both in and out of docker containers. The example above was simply my test that was w/in a docker container.

### Insecure Registry

Normally I would use https instead of http, but if you switch the registry to use http, it works as intended.

> Note: You might be led to believe this is a ssl-cert permissions issue. It is not. I made sure that the ca file accessed has the correct permissions

Comment: *"`https-proxy=https://127.0.0.1:8989`"* - this probably should be `http://` not `https://`, i.e. the same proxy URL as for normal HTTP.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Why is that?

Comment: `https://proxy:port` in the proxy URL means that the connection to a proxy should be encrypted. This would result in double encryption for `https://final-server`, i.e. an encrypted tunnel from the client to the proxy and inside this another encryption from client to final-server. Not sure if mitmproxy supports this at all, but likely it does not support both encrypted and unencrypted connection to the proxy on the same port - but this is what you have configured.

Comment: mitmproxy supports HTTPS proxying just well (at least the last few releases). Do you see anything that might be interesting in the mitmproxy event log?

Comment: @MaximilianHils, really nothing out of the ordinary.